# Contravariant Vector Component Transformation from Polar to Cartesian

Tags: vectors, tensors, polar-coordinates, transformation

I am new to tensors and I just learned that the contravarient components of a vector transforms in the following way (using Einstein summation convention)
$$A^{'i}=\frac {\partial x^{'i}}{\partial x^j}A^j$$
I want to transform the components of a vector from polar $(r,\theta)$ coordinate to cartesian $(x,y)$ coordinate. So, I use $x^{'1}=x, x^{'2}=y, x^1=r$ and $x^2=\theta$. Also, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. After performing the partial derivatives, I obtain the transformation matrix as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta  \\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But, I know from my basic vector studies that the component transformation matrix from polar to cartesian is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta  \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Can anyone please explain why this discrepancy arises? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The second matrix is not the transformation matrix from polar to Cartesian. It is a rotation matrix in Cartesian coordinates by the angle $\theta$.

Comment: Also, the covariant basis vectors in polar coordinates are $\mathbf{e}_r=\hat{r}$ and $\mathbf{e}_\theta=r\hat{\theta}$,